# xinit for correct start of awesome wm in Manjaro (xrdp)

Tags: remote-desktop, awesome-wm, manjaro, dbus

Configuration:

- Hyper-V virtual machine, Generation 1
- Manjaro 18.00 with awesome WM
- xrdp Server installed & running (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/xrdp)

Connecting to this VM from a Microsoft machine using the Remote Desktop Connection Programm leads to an incomplete(no taskbar) start of awesome WM.

Starting awesome via

```
exec /usr/bin/awesome >> ~/.cache/awesome/stdout 2>> ~/.cache/awesome/stderr
```

shows following:

```
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CreateWindow (major 1, minor 0), error=BadMatch (8)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CreateGC (major 55, minor 0), error=BadDrawable (9)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CreateWindow (major 1, minor 0), error=BadMatch (8)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CreateWindow (major 1, minor 0), error=BadMatch (8)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CopyArea (major 62, minor 0), error=BadDrawable (9)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CopyArea (major 62, minor 0), error=BadDrawable (9)
2019-02-25 15:13:23 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CopyArea (major 62, minor 0), error=BadDrawable (9)

(light-locker:3097): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:13:23.158: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:12:80: 'gtkalpha' is not a valid color name

(light-locker:3097): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:13:23.158: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:15:80: 'gtkalpha' is not a valid color name

** (light-locker:3097): ERROR **: 15:13:23.230: Environment variable XDG_SESSION_PATH not set. Is LightDM running?

(blueman-applet:3121): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:13:23.302: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:12:80: 'gtkalpha' is not a valid color name

(blueman-applet:3121): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:13:23.302: Theme parsing error: gtk.css:15:80: 'gtkalpha' is not a valid color name
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 175, in activate_name_owner
    return self.get_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 361, in get_name_owner
    's', (bus_name,), **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Could not get owner of name 'org.bluez': no such name

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sbin/blueman-applet", line 121, in <module>
    BluemanApplet()
  File "/sbin/blueman-applet", line 63, in __init__
    self.Plugins.Load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py", line 90, in Load
    __import__(self.module_path.__name__ + ".%s" % plugin, None, None, [])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/AuthAgent.py", line 9, in <module>
    import blueman.main.applet.BluezAgent as BluezAgent
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/main/applet/BluezAgent.py", line 23, in <module>
    from blueman.bluez.Agent import Agent, AgentMethod
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/bluez/Agent.py", line 48, in <module>
    class Agent(dbus.service.Object):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/bluez/Agent.py", line 56, in Agent
    @AgentMethod
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/bluez/Agent.py", line 38, in AgentMethod
    if BlueZInterface.get_interface_version()[0] < 5:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blueman/bluez/BlueZInterface.py", line 16, in get_interface_version
    obj = dbus.SystemBus().get_object('org.bluez', '/')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 241, in get_object
    follow_name_owner_changes=follow_name_owner_changes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 248, in __init__
    self._named_service = conn.activate_name_owner(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 180, in activate_name_owner
    self.start_service_by_name(bus_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/bus.py", line 278, in start_service_by_name
    'su', (bus_name, flags)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
2019-02-25 15:14:00 W: awesome: xerror:1038: X error: request=CopyArea (major 62, minor 0), error=BadDrawable (9)
```

Content of ~/.xinitrc is

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ~/.xinitrc
#
# Executed by startx (run your window manager from here)

userresources=$HOME/.Xresources
usermodmap=$HOME/.Xmodmap
sysresources=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xresources
sysmodmap=/etc/X11/xinit/.Xmodmap

# awesome is kept as default
DEFAULT_SESSION=awesome

# merge in defaults and keymaps

if [ -f $sysresources ]; then
    xrdb -merge $sysresources
fi

if [ -f $sysmodmap ]; then
    xmodmap $sysmodmap
fi

if [ -f "$userresources" ]; then
    xrdb -merge "$userresources"
fi

if [ -f "$usermodmap" ]; then
    xmodmap "$usermodmap"
fi

# start some nice programs

if [ -d /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d ] ; then
    for f in /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/?*.sh ; do
        [ -x "$f" ] && . "$f"
    done
    unset f
fi

get_session(){
    local dbus_args=(--sh-syntax --exit-with-session)
    case $1 in
        awesome) dbus_args+=(awesome) ;;
        bspwm) dbus_args+=(bspwm-session) ;;
        budgie) dbus_args+=(budgie-desktop) ;;
        cinnamon) dbus_args+=(cinnamon-session) ;;
        deepin) dbus_args+=(startdde) ;;
        enlightenment) dbus_args+=(enlightenment_start) ;;
        fluxbox) dbus_args+=(startfluxbox) ;;
        gnome) dbus_args+=(gnome-session) ;;
        i3|i3wm) dbus_args+=(i3 --shmlog-size 0) ;;
        jwm) dbus_args+=(jwm) ;;
        kde) dbus_args+=(startkde) ;;
        lxde) dbus_args+=(startlxde) ;;
        lxqt) dbus_args+=(lxqt-session) ;;
        mate) dbus_args+=(mate-session) ;;
        xfce) dbus_args+=(xfce4-session) ;;
        openbox) dbus_args+=(openbox-session) ;;
        *) dbus_args+=($DEFAULT_SESSION) ;;
    esac

    echo "dbus-launch ${dbus_args[*]}"
}

exec $(get_session)
```

Can someone give a .xinitrc file or some how-to for a correct setup of xrdp? Log in without Remote Desktop Connection, everything works fine.

Could it be, that lightdm executes /etc/lightdm/Xsession and not only ~/.xinitrc?...

Answer (score 0):

This issue isn't directly related to AwesomeWM. The stack trace above is in Python, while AwesomeWM is written in Lua. BlueZ is the bluetooth stack. In any case, it makes little sense over a remote desktop. It isn't started by AwesomeWM, so I guess you have another script starting it (maybe from AwesomeWM own `rc.lua`? Another possibility is that you have some scripts in `~/.config/autostart/` and they (somehow) are executed (neither AwesomeWM nor `.xinitrc` do that).

In both case, the answer is "don't start bluetooth services when using a remote desktop, the dbus sessions are apparently different and it wont work"